# Where is the flaw in my algorithm for constructing a sorted array of month-year dates given a min and a max?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

What I want:

Given two month-year pairs such as (5/2015), (2/2016) I want to construct an array like

```
[ '5/2015', '6/2015', '7/2015', '8/2015', '9/2015', '10/2015', '11/2015', '12/2015', '1/2016', '2/2016' ]
```

My algorithm is

```
var parts1 = DateToMmDdYyyy(new Date(SortedByDate[0].Created)).split('/'),
    parts2 = DateToMmDdYyyy(new Date(SortedByDate[SortedByDate.length - 1].Created)).split('/');
var y1 = +parts1[2],
    m1 = +parts1[0], 
    y2 = +parts2[2],
    m2 = +parts2[0],
    Labels = new Array();
while ( y1 <= y2 && m1 <= m2 ) 
{
    Labels.push(y1 + '/' + m1);
    if ( m1 < 12 ) { ++m1; }
    else { ++y1; m1 = 1; }
}
```

and after running it with valid `y1`, `m1`, `y2` and `m2` values I am ending up with an empty array `Labels`. Where am I going wrong here? And is it possible to make this more elegant, compact, efficient, readable and correct?

Comment: Where are `DateToMmDdYyyy` and `SortedByDate` defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop condition should be something like

```
while ( y1 < y2 || y1 == y2 && m1 <= m2 )
```

Otherwise, since `m2 < m1`, the loop will not run, even if `y1 < y2`.

```js
var y1 = 2015, m1 = 6, 
    y2 = 2016, m2 = 2,
    labels = [];
while ( y1 < y2 || y1 == y2 && m1 <= m2 ) {
  labels.push(y1 + '/' + m1);
  if ( m1 < 12 ) { ++m1; }
  else { ++y1; m1 = 1; }
}
snippet.log(labels);
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 --><script src="https://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Loop through the array. concatenate with "0/" + month/year pair.

```
Date.parse("0/mm/yyyy")
```

Date.parse will return timestamp in millisecond. Now you have got integer array. sort it and accordingly change the position of values in original array while you are sorting the timestamp array.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I noticed is the m1 <= m2 condition, as 03/2015 is less than 02/2015 but wont match your condition.
What you need to do is something like (y1 < y2 || (y1 == y2 && m1 <= m2))

Hope this helps you. Regards